# ssh2_connect(): Error startingup SSH connection(-8): Unable to exchange encryption keys

Tags: encryption, ssh-keys, libssh2

I'm doing some coding with libssh2 to connect to Huawei routers. On some routers works fine, on others just echo this error:

"Warning: ssh2_connect(): Error startingup SSH connection(-8): Unable to exchange encryption keys in (...)".

I used putty on same routers and the sessions logs are identical:

```
2015-05-27 12:02:19 Server version: SSH-2.0-HUAWEI-1.5
2015-05-27 12:02:19 Using SSH protocol version 2
2015-05-27 12:02:19 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
2015-05-27 12:02:19 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2015-05-27 12:02:19 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
2015-05-27 12:02:32 Host key fingerprint is:
2015-05-27 12:02:32 ssh-rsa 512 8a:07:9a:28:1d:4d:22:4c:18:35:4f:18:eb:ba:9e:b3
2015-05-27 12:02:32 Initialised AES-128 CBC client->server encryption
2015-05-27 12:02:32 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
2015-05-27 12:02:32 Initialised AES-128 CBC server->client encryption
2015-05-27 12:02:32 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
```

Can you help me?
Thanks!